# How to expose User authorized API scope in Azure AD B2C Application

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a Web API that is registered in an Azure AD B2C directory, secured by tokens from that same directory. To do that I have created an Application and created a scope.

I have a 3rd party that would also like to use this AD for their audience, who will access some of my API on behalf of the guest.

I wanted to create a new scope for this purpose and have the AD prompt the guest to allow the application to access their data on their behalf.

For some reason, when I create a scope I am only given the option of "Admin Consent". The "User Consent" fields that are shown in so many blog posts and instructions are not showing for me.

I have tried to register the 3rd Party Applications and API Applications in both the B2C blades and the AAD blades of the Azure Portal but the result is always the same.

Is there a Property or setting somewhere that needs to be ticked in order to enable User Authorized scopes?

Answer (score 0):

There’s no such thing as OAuth2.0 consent in AAD B2C, only Admin consent is offered, as it’s aimed for your first party apps.
The user consent screens you’re seeing online are in regards to Azure AD, not AAD B2C.

For service partner integration, you can follow this example to create such a consent. https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/service-consent

Comment: Thanks @Jas - I suspected that might be the case, but I am also getting the same result when I try to configure the App in AAD (admittedly the ADD that sits behind the B2C)? Is there something special about an AAD created as part of  B2C provisioning?

Comment: When registering the app, choose the first option (Accounts in this org only), then you will see the AAD OAuth2 consent screen as long as you haven’t Admin Consented the permissions. Nothing special happening here, as you say the AAD is behind AAD B2C, so an AAD App Reg, using AAD endpoints of your B2C directory will behave like vanilla AAD.

Comment: Thanks again, but if I were creating a commercial API like Box or QuoteOfTheDay, in which AD would I register that? I don't want to limit the audience to only the users in my AAD, surely? Besides which, your suggestion does *not* show the User Consented settings - it's only the Admin Consented options that appear when creating a new Scope (new App from AAD, no matter which Account Types are selected)

Comment: For a commercial API, where in which you want other partners to leverage, using Application credentials, AAD suffices. Where you want the partners to allow their users to consume your API, then you’d want AAD B2C (so the end user could consent with an identity you hold via local account or federated Idp) using the sample I linked. That’s similar to an app (partner) integrating with PayPal (where your api is PayPal).